# Visual Studio 2013: IDE tab filename is <SomeFileName.aspx:1>?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Pretty much what the title says... I have a file open and the tab title is `SomeFileName.aspx:1`

What's that `:1` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the naming convention for Visual Studio when the window is cloned. Sometimes, however, Visual Studio just gets confused and names it that way.